# Computation of exponential and logarithmic maps on Riemann manifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry, computational-mathematics, computational-geometry, geodesic, principal-component-analysis

In my computational problem, I have a Riemann submanifold $S^{1000}$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{300000}$. I can numerically compute the induced metric tensor and the Jacobian. I have no analytical expression of these quantities; they all come from large-scale computations.

I would like to compute the exponential map and logarithmic map on my $S^{1000}$ manifold. I expect to do so by numerically solving a large number of equations, which I can afford with high-peformance computing. I want to have the exponential and logarithmic maps to compute geodesics on $S^{1000}$, eventually.

**My question is:**
How can the exponential maps and logarithmic maps be computed when there is no analytical expression? What systems of equations do I need to solve?

Thank you,
Luke

Comment: Computing the exponential map is equivalent to computing the geodesics. There are basically two ways to solve for a geodesic. One is to start with a point and a tangent vector at that point and solve a second order nonlinear ODE. The other is to start with two points and solve for the shortest curve joining them. Both can be done numerically. But what’s the goal here?

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure about "Computing the exponential map is equivalent to computing the geodesics.". The two are related to each other, but the exponential map is an operator that projects a quantity from the tangent space onto the manifold. For now, the goal that I have is to be able to project a point to/from the manifold from/to the tangent space of a fixed point of the manifold.

Comment: The exponential map projects a tangent vector onto the manifold by projecting onto the geodesic whose velocity is the tangent vector. So if you've found a way to compute the exponential map, then you have found a way to compute all of the geodesics that start at a given point. And vice versa.

Comment: I presume that I have found neither method, which is why I posted here!

Comment: Focus on how to solve for a geodesic. Exponential map is just jargon.

Comment: Consider I have a 2 sphere and that I have 100 random points on the sphere. I pick another point on the sphere, let's call it A. On A, I know the tangent space equation. Now, I want to project all the other 100 points from the sphere to the tangent space centred at A. And I want to do be able to do the other way round, from the tangent space back to the sphere. Pretend we do not know the analytical expression of the exp and log maps. How can I accomplish my goals above numerically?

Comment: Do you really need this only for the standard 2-sphere?

Comment: No, I don't. My problem, as stated, concerns a Riemann submanifold $S^{1000}$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{300000}$. However, I mentioned the 2-sphere problem to make it less complicated. If I obtain an answer for my latest reply for the 2 sphere, I will know how to tackle my real problem.